# session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 74 error with ChromeDriver Chrome using Selenium

Tags: automation

I know by default this Demo Project Chrome Browser set
I just stuck with Chrome issue :
When I try Run Test "Create Account: WEBTestCreateNewAccount" it is Fail and I am getting into error message:
SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 74 though Chrome v74 is installed

Steps I found and done so far, I followed Solution from this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54927496/how-to-download-older-versions-of-chrome-from-a-google-official-site

My issue that when I found version mentioned on NuGet Packages 74.0.3729.6 and attach to "Version Information Tool" I am getting following link
https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Win_x64/638880/
it is installation for Chromium instead of Chrome Browser for Windows 10 64 bit

Any thoughts or may be you come across issues like that

Thank you very much

Comment: I resolved issue with Chrome - just reinstall latest version and installed latest NuGet packages 

Now when I run Test Case CreateAccount have following fail error: 

Microsoft.Dynamics365.UIAutomation.Sample.Web.CreateAccount.WEBTestCreateNewAccount threw exception:Login page failed 
Any thoughts for resolving this one, what debugging break point I should add

Answer (score 0):

> It is an installation file for Chromium instead of Chrome Browser for Windows 10 64 bit.

As mentioned in the first link, older versions of Chrome aren't typically available after Google stops distributing them (unless you can find offline installations files someone else has saved).

That said, this is probably a good thing overall. Chromium installs into different directories than "regular" Chrome, which means that you are less likely to have issues running them side-by-side.

Also, while there are different forks of Chromium, in this instance it would seem unlikely that you would find any incompatibility that would prevent your from running your demo project with Selenium.

> `This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 74`, though Chrome v74 is installed.

Unfortunately, a particular version of ChromeDriver may only supports particular versions of Chrome/Chromium. As Chrome/Chromium is consistently being updated, sometimes a break in compatibility can occur in the middle of a major version.

The only solutions are to find a compatible version of ChromeDriver or roll back you version of Chrome/Chromium to one that your given version of ChromeDriver supports.

Comment: Thank you @Anaksunaman

Comment: Thanks 
I installed latest Chrome Browser 76.0.3809.132 (64 bit) and Install NuGet packages: 
Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver v.76.0.3809.12600
Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver          Latest Stable v. 76.0.0 
 


Unable to copy file "C:\Users\ikeselman\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\EasyRepro1\EasyRepro-develop\packages\Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver.76.0.3809.12600\build\..\driver\win32\chromedriver.exe" to "C:\Users\ikeselman\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\EasyRepro1\EasyRepro-develop\Microsoft.Dynamics365.UIAutomation.Sample\bin\Debug\chromedriver.exe"